# Why I can't upload image to server with React.js and Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload

I've made my form and I'd like to make a POST request to send my data to my database. All my data is sent server-side, except for the photo (coverPhoto) which I'm uploading. When `console.log(JSON.stringify(formDataWithPhotoUrl))` all the information is available, including coverPhoto and its value

> {"title":"polunete","description":"ioee","targetAmount":"111000","duration":"20","coverPhoto":"blob:http://localhost:3000/266aea96-cd17-49cb-8045-e0d5fe82fd75"}

but when I launch my POST request all the data has values and goes into my database except coverPhoto:

```
message: "Projet créé avec succès"
project: 
comments: []
coverPhoto: null
coverPhotoUrl: null
createdAt: "21 juin 2023"
createdBy: {_id: '648dfc3b1aa0b7a1840a891e', name: 'mion'}
createdByUsername: "mion"
currentAmount: 0
description: "ioee"
donations: []
duration: 20
progress: 0
targetAmount: 111000
title: "polunete"
updatedAt: "2023-06-21T00:50:31.930Z"
_id: "64924958baf1231c36f88541"
```

which is null.
Here is my Form Page :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function TeamDetailsContent() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: '',
    description: '',
    targetAmount: '',
    duration: '',
    coverPhoto: ''
  });

  const [coverPhoto, setCoverPhoto] = useState('');


  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const fileName = file.name;
    const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    console.log(fileUrl);
    
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, coverPhoto: fileName }));
    setCoverPhoto(fileUrl);
    
  };
  
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, [name]: value }));
  };

  console.log(formData);
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const session = localStorage.getItem('session');
  
  const formDataWithPhotoUrl = {
    ...formData,
    coverPhoto: coverPhoto,
  };

  // Mettre à jour formData avec la photo
  setFormData(formDataWithPhotoUrl);

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(formDataWithPhotoUrl),
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Set-Cookie': session,
    },
  };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(formDataWithPhotoUrl));
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/project/create', requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error creating project:', error);
    });
};

  

  let publicUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/';
  return (
    <>
            <div className="col-xl-6 col-lg-6">
              <div className="join-team__right">
                <form className="join-team__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xl-12">
                      <div className="join-team__input">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Nom du projet"
                          name="title"
                          value={formData.title}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xl-12">
                      <div className="join-team__input">
                        <textarea
                          placeholder="Description du projet"
                          name="description"
                          value={formData.description}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        ></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xl-12">
                      <div className="join-team__input">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Somme à atteindre"
                          name="targetAmount"
                          value={formData.targetAmount}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xl-12">
                      <div className="join-team__input">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Nombre de jours"
                          name="duration"
                          value={formData.duration}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xl-12">
                      <div className="join-team__input">
                        <input type="file" name="coverPhoto" onChange={handleFileChange} />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xl-12">
                      <div className="join-team__btn-box">
                        <button type="submit" className="thm-btn join-team__btn">
                          Créer le projet
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my projectController Server:

```
const Project = require('../models/project');
const User = require('../models/user');
const moment = require('moment');



const formatDate = (date) => {
  const options = {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
  };

  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR', options).format(new Date(date));
};


exports.createProject = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title, description, targetAmount, duration, category } = req.body;
    const userId = req.user._id;

    // Vérifier si un projet avec le même nom existe déjà
    const existingProject = await Project.findOne({ title });

    if (existingProject) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Un projet avec le même nom existe déjà' });
    }

    const currentDate = new Date();

    // Récupérer le nom du créateur
    const creator = await User.findById(userId);
    if (!creator) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Utilisateur introuvable' });
    }
    const creatorName = creator.name;

    const newProject = await Project.create({
      title,
      description,
      targetAmount,
      duration,
      category,
      createdBy: userId,
      createdByUsername: creatorName, // Enregistrer le nom du créateur dans le projet
      createdAt: currentDate,
      coverPhoto: req.file ? req.file.filename : null, // Vérifier si une photo de couverture a été téléchargée
    });

    const formattedCreatedAt = formatDate(currentDate); // Formatage de la date

    let coverPhotoUrl = null;
    if (newProject.coverPhoto) {
      coverPhotoUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/uploads/' + newProject.coverPhoto;
    }

    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Projet créé avec succès',
      project: {
        ...newProject._doc,
        createdBy: {
          _id: creator._id,
          name: creatorName,
        },
        createdAt: formattedCreatedAt,
        coverPhotoUrl: coverPhotoUrl, // Utiliser la variable coverPhotoUrl
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Échec de la création du projet', error });
  }
};
```

projectRoutes :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const projectController = require('../controllers/projectController');
const authMiddleware = require('../middlewares/authMiddleware');
const fileSystem = require('fs');
const multer = require('multer');
const Project = require('../models/project');


// Configuration de multer pour la gestion du téléchargement de fichiers
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uploadDir = 'public/uploads/';
      if (!fileSystem.existsSync(uploadDir)) {
        fileSystem.mkdirSync(uploadDir, { recursive: true });
      }
      cb(null, uploadDir);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      // Génération d'un nom de fichier unique avec l'extension .png
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
      const filename = file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix + '.png';
      cb(null, filename);
    }
  }
);
  
  const upload = multer({ storage: storage });



  // Créer un projet (authentification requise)
router.post('/create', authMiddleware, upload.single('coverPhoto'), projectController.createProject);
```

And then my Server :

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge:  60* 60 * 1000 // 1 heures en millisecondes
  }
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/uploads', express.static('public/uploads'));

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.status(401).json({ message: 'La session à expiré' });
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden' });
}

app.use('/project', projectRoutes);
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use('/user', userRoutes);

app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/user/register');
});

app.get('/profile', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Authorized access' });
});

app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Login page' });
});

connectDB().then(() => {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 5000');
  });
});
```

I want to be able to store all the information I enter in my form in my database. For the moment, everything except coverPhoto remains null, so that's the value I want to send with the others.